# differences in pandas nsmallest method when applied to columns and to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
         I_q_0_sub  I_q_1_sub   I_q_2_sub   I_q_3_sub   I_q_4_sub   I_q_5_sub
q
0.016513    1.0     1.086586    0.396789    0.030419    0.167913    0.626752
0.017082    1.0     1.088389    0.397858    0.029408    0.166246    0.629824
0.017651    1.0     1.088213    0.398661    0.028985    0.167011    0.628466
0.018221    1.0     1.085454    0.396699    0.027980    0.165895    0.627416
0.018790    1.0     1.078595    0.395192    0.026815    0.165361    0.625276
0.019360    1.0     1.076327    0.393727    0.026964    0.166564    0.624980
0.019929    1.0     1.076141    0.392881    0.026499    0.166089    0.624884
0.020498    1.0     1.074617    0.391246    0.026023    0.164293    0.625018
0.021068    1.0     1.074573    0.389804    0.025534    0.165650    0.623080
0.021637    1.0     1.074772    0.390498    0.025619    0.166404    0.622398
0.022207    1.0     1.072407    0.389034    0.025418    0.165267    0.620503
0.022776    1.0     1.068778    0.389453    0.025364    0.165631    0.621173
0.023345    1.0     1.069125    0.388866    0.025222    0.165374    0.622733
0.023915    1.0     1.067703    0.389035    0.024862    0.164636    0.621182
0.024484    1.0     1.063856    0.387513    0.025124    0.164992    0.619048
0.025054    1.0     1.063000    0.388187    0.025446    0.164981    0.617603
0.025623    1.0     1.063995    0.387414    0.025752    0.165825    0.617720
0.026192    1.0     1.061866    0.387479    0.025579    0.165128    0.618729
0.026762    1.0     1.060178    0.384343    0.025603    0.165227    0.616478
0.027331    1.0     1.057169    0.384075    0.025644    0.164989    0.617416
0.027900    1.0     1.054479    0.384566    0.026249    0.164863    0.615285
0.028470    1.0     1.054914    0.383443    0.026397    0.166146    0.616100
0.029039    1.0     1.054963    0.383084    0.026302    0.165473    0.617631
0.029609    1.0     1.052284    0.382753    0.026824    0.164973    0.614430
0.030178    1.0     1.053644    0.383991    0.027040    0.166437    0.615252
0.030747    1.0     1.051703    0.384502    0.027135    0.166372    0.614781
0.031317    1.0     1.048446    0.383240    0.027762    0.165991    0.614492
0.031886    1.0     1.050411    0.382216    0.027915    0.167335    0.613784
0.032455    1.0     1.052862    0.383122    0.028400    0.167722    0.615104
0.033025    1.0     1.048664    0.384156    0.029077    0.167987    0.614716
0.033594    1.0     1.045783    0.384269    0.029518    0.166930    0.614234
0.034163    1.0     1.049077    0.384258    0.030929    0.168138    0.614413
0.034733    1.0     1.047248    0.384060    0.031300    0.168228    0.613657
0.035302    1.0     1.044294    0.385330    0.031312    0.168637    0.612413
0.035872    1.0     1.045500    0.384630    0.031975    0.169539    0.613903
0.036441    1.0     1.047008    0.385461    0.032721    0.169195    0.614401
0.037010    1.0     1.046601    0.386015    0.033526    0.171218    0.615378
0.037580    1.0     1.039578    0.385855    0.034593    0.170812    0.611779
0.038149    1.0     1.042296    0.386241    0.035050    0.170443    0.611111
0.038718    1.0     1.041640    0.385285    0.035902    0.171739    0.611083
0.039288    1.0     1.046594    0.388858    0.037150    0.174225    0.613183
0.039857    1.0     1.045652    0.390708    0.038682    0.173627    0.613125
0.040426    1.0     1.046337    0.392301    0.039181    0.174176    0.612989
0.040996    1.0     1.041239    0.392167    0.039861    0.175146    0.612321
0.041565    1.0     1.040595    0.393418    0.040991    0.174704    0.613320
```

I'm getting different values when I apply the nsmallest method for individual columns and for the entire df. As you can see, for individual columns, I got this:

```
df["I_q_0_sub"].iloc[15:60].nsmallest(n = 5).mean()
1.0

df["I_q_1_sub"].iloc[15:60].nsmallest(n = 5).mean()
1.041069402080646

df["I_q_2_sub"].iloc[15:60].nsmallest(n = 5).mean()
0.3828830431385227

df["I_q_3_sub"].iloc[15:60].nsmallest(n = 5).mean()
0.025197931800085817

df["I_q_4_sub"].iloc[15:60].nsmallest(n = 5).mean()
0.16474921466342365

df["I_q_4_sub"].iloc[15:60].nsmallest(n = 5).mean()
0.61174148613757
```

Entire df:

```
df.iloc[15:60].nsmallest(n = 5, columns=formFactor_sub.columns).mean()
I_q_0_sub    1.000000
I_q_1_sub    1.041069
I_q_2_sub    0.388593
I_q_3_sub    0.037279
I_q_4_sub    0.172569
I_q_5_sub    0.611923
```

So values for the individual columns are different from the values from the whole dataframe and that can not be. Any hints about why is this happening would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

nsmallest works only with the column parameter, that is it has to find the nsmallest rows for a particular column. If you pass all the columns as you have done using columns=formFactor_sub.columns, all it does is that it returns the nsmallest values by the first column.

Consider this dataframe,

```
    a   b   c
0   1   7   1
1   10  9   2
2   8   3   3
3   11  6   4
4   -1  1   5
5   5   8   6
6   15  2   7

df.nsmallest(3, columns = df.columns)
```

returns

```
    a   b   c
4   -1  1   5
0   1   7   1
5   5   8   6
```

which is same as what you would get with

```
df.nsmallest(3, columns = 'a')
```

But it is different from what you would get with

```
df['b'].nsmallest(3)
```

or

```
df['c'].nsmallest(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. It makes sense! Is there a more "pythonic" way of getting the same result as I get from individual columns?

Comment: It's in a way sorting the dataframe on the first column and returning the corresponding values for the rest of the columns. So I guess the most pythonic way is to go the Series way, which is what you are doing

Comment: Thanks once again! My way works as intended but it's very repetitive though